# Erasing an element from 2D vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a unsymmetrical vector in 2D.

```
vector< vector<int> > Test
```

where Test =

```
         2 4 6 5 7 
         6 5 7 9 10
         5 9 10
         9 10
```

I am reading the row 1 and if any element of this is present in other rows then delete it.
for eaxmple.. After reading row 1, i have to remove 6, 5, and 7 from other rows.

However, It is not working

Here is the code i am trying

```
Test[i].erase(Test[i].begin()+j);
```

where i = row and j is col.

My code is :

```
for (i =0; i < Test.size();i++)
        {
        for (j=0; j < Test[i].size();j++)
                {
                // removed repeated element
                if (i >0)
                        {
                        Test[i].erase(Test[i].begin() +j);
                        }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Please refine `is not working`. We won't magically find out what is happening with your code.

Comment: Based on this 2D vector, my final output should looks like {2,4,6,5,7}{9,10}, there is no third and fourth row as their elements are repeated before.

Comment: what is the expected output and what is the output you are getting. if your erasing elements isn't i and j going to be off?

Comment: Can you add your complete code? One line is not enough to determine the bug you may have.

Comment: Both `test[i].erase(test[i].begin()+j)` and `test.at(i).erase(test.at(i).begin()+j)` work when I test it locally. Can you post the whole code so we can check if the mistake is anywhere else?

Comment: And what is the result? I don't see any code to compare values of two vector elements with each other, so I guess the output is not much like what you wanted. (If I had to guess this at an interview without running code, I'd say it is {2 4 6 5 7}{5 9}{9}{10} -- that is, the complete first row and the data from odd-numbered positions in the other rows.)

Comment: Keep the row one. remove all elements from row two which are present in row 1. remove all elements from row 3 which are present in row 1 and row 2 and so on. This is the problem.

Comment: The efficient way to tackle a problem like this is to keep track of the values that should be removed as you run your loop. You can use a `std::unordered_set` for that. To remove elements from a vector use `std::remove_if`.

Comment: @snoze: I understood what you _wanted_ the result to be. Two people (including myself) asked what the result of your program _was_. Clearly it was different from what you wanted, but you have not said anything else about it. It can help to understand what errors are in a program if you can see exactly what errors are in its output.

Comment: David, I have posted my code above and the results too. Based on my code i was unable to get the results I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is nor very nice but it works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v =
    {
        { 2, 4, 6, 5, 7 }, 
        { 6, 5, 7, 9, 10 },
        { 5, 9, 10 },
        { 9, 10 }
    };

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    if ( !v.empty() )
    {
        for ( auto it = std::next( v.begin() ); it != v.end(); ++it )
        {
            auto is_present = [&]( int x )
            {
                return std::find_if( v.begin(), it,
                    [x]( const std::vector<int> &v1 )
                    {
                        return std::find( v1.begin(), v1.end(), x ) != v1.end();
                    } ) != it; 
            };

            it->erase( std::remove_if( it->begin(), it->end(), is_present ), 
                       it->end() );
        }
    }


    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
2 4 6 5 7 
6 5 7 9 10 
5 9 10 
9 10 

2 4 6 5 7 
9 10
```

Comment: Answer should be {2 4 6 5 7 } {9 10 } {} {}

Comment: If I understood the question right, not only the first line should be edited.

Comment: First line should remain intact. Only elements from other lines to be get removed if they appear before.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the values encountered in each row in a set, and then query every element in a new row for existence in that set. Such a function would look like this :

```
void RemoveRowDuplicates(vector<vector<int>> &v)
{
    std::set<int> vals;

    for(auto &vec : v)
    {
        vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](int k){
            return vals.find(k) != vals.end();
        }), vec.end());
        vals.insert(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you think is `Test[i].begin()+j`? Is ist a set of elements you want to erase? I don't think so. It should be just an iterator, that points to a **single element**, but you want to delete **all elements**, that are already in your datastructure.

If I understood, what you want to do, try:

```
for(int j = 0; j < Test.size(); j++){            //iterate over other rows
    if(j == i)
        continue;
    for(int k = 0; k < Test[j].size(); k++){     //iterate over elements of the rows
        int elementToRemove = (Test[j])[k];
        vector<int>::iterator it = Test[i].begin();
        while (it != Test[i].end()) {            //iterate over row i
           if((*it) == elementToRemove){         //erase the element if it matches the actual
               it = Test[i].erase(it);    
           }else{
               it++;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

You could execute the code for every possible i. Maybe start form `i = 0 to n`. If I refer to your code, that you added put the code above in between your

```
for (i =0; i < Test.size();i++){
    //my code here...
}
```

**Edit:** Used iterator now to delete. The first version was not correct.

**Edit2:** Changed the index of the first loop and added continue statement.

Comment: This should have been `Test[i]`... fixed it. So this code should be in your for loop, where you iterate over i.

Comment: Still output order is not perfect but partially it is working. Output should be  {2,4,6,5,7}{9,10} last two line elements are repeated. So removed them.

Comment: In this case it would be better to also check if the elements exist in the rows above... look at the new version. It compares with every row except the actual one.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
int i = 0;
for ( int j = i+1; j < Test.size(); ++j )
{
   for ( int k = 0; k < Test[i].size(); ++k )
   {
      std::vector<int>::iterator iter = Test[j].begin();
      std::vector<int>::iterator end = Test[j].end();
      for ( ; iter != end; )
      {
         if ( *iter == Test[i][k] )
         {
            iter = Test[j].erase(iter);
         }
         else
         {
            ++iter;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this one but somehow 'Segmentation fault'

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following 2D vector

myVector=

1 2 3 4 5 -6

6 7 8 -9

8 -1 -2 1 0

Suppose we want to delete the element myVector[row][column] for appropriate  row and column indices.

Look at the following code:

```
void delete_element(vector<int>& temp, col) 
  {
     temp.erase(temp.begin()+col);
  }

int main()
 {
  //Assume that the vector 'myVector' is already present.
    cin>>row>>column;
    delete_element(myVector[row],column);
 }
```

What we basically do is,we get the row and column of the element to be deleted. Now as this 2D vector is a vector of vectors, we pass the vector(the row containing the element to be deleted) and the column as parameters to a function. Note that the row-vector is passed as a reference ('&' in vector parameter).
Now the problem becomes quite as simple as deleting an element from a 1D vector.

Hope this helps!