# Delete item from multidimensional vector MQL4/C++

Tags: c++, mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

Could you please help me to delete an item from a multidimensional array? For example how can I delete the first range of **in_matrix** below?

---

```
vector<CArrayInt*> int_matrix;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    CArrayInt *int_vector = new CArrayInt(); 
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        int_vector.Add(OrderTicket());
     }
int_matrix.Add(int_vector);
}

int_matrix.Delete(0);            //// DOESN'T WORK
```

---

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out the documentation for `std::vector` at cppreference.com. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erasing an element from 2D vector c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418609/erasing-an-element-from-2d-vector-c)